# knit document using printr displaying raw HTML not rendered HTML

Tags: html, r, knitr

I am using the `printr` package to render help pages for my `iemisc` package in a rmarkdown HTML document; however, the HTML is not rendered.

Please refer to https://www.ecoccs.com/R_Examples/help.html for the HTML Web page & https://www.ecoccs.com/R_Examples/help.Rmd for the rmarkdown document that created the HTML Web page.

This is the call to render the rmarkdown document at the command line:

```
rmarkdown::render("help.Rmd", html_document(theme = "readable", highlight = "kate",
toc = TRUE, toc_depth = 2, toc_float = TRUE))
```

What needs to be done to have the HTML help page properly render the HTML?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please report `xfun::session_info(c('rmarkdown', 'printr'))` in your post.

Comment: @YihuiXie I have updated the files with the requested information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Pandoc version is 1.19.2.4, which is too low. You need to update Pandoc: https://pandoc.org/installing.html

Technically, **printr** generates raw HTML blocks for help pages using ```` ```{=html} ````, which is not supported by lower versions of Pandoc.

Note that if you use RStudio, it usually bundles a relatively new version of Pandoc, in which case you don't need to install Pandoc separately.